# Image not showing tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a switch button but the image "mid.png" is not showing.
Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

def switch_button():
    global btn_state
    btn_state=1

    def test(event):
        global btn_state
        if btn_state == 1:
            win_btn.config(image=mid_btn)
            window.after(100,None)
            win_btn.config(image=on_btn)
            btn_state=0
        else:
            win_btn.config(image=mid_btn)
            window.after(100,None)
            win_btn.config(image=off_btn)
            btn_state=1

    on_btn=PhotoImage(file='on.png')
    mid_btn=PhotoImage(file='mid.png')
    off_btn=PhotoImage(file='off.png')

    win_btn = Label(window, image=off_btn)
    win_btn.bind("<Button-1>",test)
    win_btn.pack()
    
switch_button()

window.geometry("400x500")
window.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to show "mid.png" before it switches to "on.png" or "off.png" so the switch can be more smooth

Comment: Did you save the image in the same folder where you save your ```.py ``` file if not then give the path of the image

Comment: What are you calling `window.after(100,None)`? What do you think that's doing for you?

Comment: @UjjwalDash Yes, it's in the same folder.

Comment: @BryanOakley ```window.after(100,None)``` it's to show the image 100ms after the first one. Before it was ```window.after(100,win_btn.config(image=off_btn))``` but it did not work.

Comment: `window.after(100, None)` is the same as calling `time.sleep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `win_btn.update_idletasks()` before calling `window.after(100, None)`.

However I suggest to use `after()` to schedule the change of image instead of using it just like `sleep()`.

Below is a modified `switch_button()`:

```py
def switch_button():
    def test(event):
        btn_state = win_btn['image'] # get the current image variable name
        win_btn.config(image=mid_btn) # change to 'mid' state
        # schedule to change to target state 100ms later
        window.after(100, win_btn.config, {'image': off_btn if btn_state == 'ON' else on_btn})

    on_btn = PhotoImage(file='on.png', name='ON') # set image variable name to ON
    mid_btn = PhotoImage(file='mid.png')
    off_btn = PhotoImage(file='off.png', name='OFF') # set image variable name to OFF

    win_btn = Label(window, image=off_btn)
    win_btn.bind("<Button-1>", test)
    win_btn.pack()
```